# python masking each day in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, mask

I have to make a daily sum on a dataframe but only if at least 70% of the daily data is not NaN. If it is then this day must not be taken into account. Is there a way to create such a mask? My dataframe is more than 17 years of hourly data.

my data is something like this:

```
                    clear skies  all skies     Lab
2015-02-26 13:00:00     597.5259   376.1830  307.62
2015-02-26 14:00:00     461.2014   244.0453  199.94
2015-02-26 15:00:00     283.9003   166.5772  107.84
2015-02-26 16:00:00      93.5099    50.7761   23.27
2015-02-26 17:00:00       1.1559     0.2784    0.91
                         ...        ...     ...
2015-12-05 07:00:00      95.0285    29.1006   45.23
2015-12-05 08:00:00     241.8822   120.1049  113.41
2015-12-05 09:00:00     363.8040   196.0568  244.78
2015-12-05 10:00:00     438.2264   274.3733  461.28
2015-12-05 11:00:00     456.3396   330.6650  447.15
```

if I groupby and aggregate than there is no way to know if in any day there was some lack of data and some days will have lower sums and therefore lowering my monthly means

Comment: `groupby` date and do an aggregation. Without any data sample, I cannot help further.

Comment: You may want to think about a more specific title for the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, use `groupby` to group the data by date and then write an appropriate selection. This is an example that would sum all days (assuming regular data points, 24 per day) with less than 50% of `nan` entries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a date range
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/1/2021', freq='H')

# create random data
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))}, index = date_rng)

# set some values to nan
df["data"][df["data"] > 50] = np.nan

# looks like this
df.head(20)

# sum everything where less than 50% are nan
df.groupby(df.index.date).sum()[df.isna().groupby(df.index.date).sum() < 12]
```

Example output:

```
            data
2018-01-01    NaN
2018-01-02    NaN
2018-01-03  487.0
2018-01-04    NaN
2018-01-05  421.0
...           ...
2020-12-28    NaN
2020-12-29    NaN
2020-12-30    NaN
2020-12-31  392.0
2021-01-01    0.0
```

Comment: well what you said absolutely works but I have another question if you can spare an answer. I can't resample it using the month=day.resample('M').mean() to take the monthly average. since it says: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index' 
kind of a noob here sorry

Comment: I found it! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution - you may find it useful & flexible:

```py
# pip install convtools
from convtools import conversion as c

total_number = c.ReduceFuncs.Count()
total_not_none = c.ReduceFuncs.Count(where=c.item("amount").is_not(None))
total_sum = c.ReduceFuncs.Sum(c.item("amount"))

input_data = []  # e.g. iterable of dicts
converter = (
    c.group_by(
        c.item("key1"),
        c.item("key2"),
    )
    .aggregate(
        {
            "key1": c.item("key1"),
            "key2": c.item("key2"),
            "sum_if_70": c.if_(
                total_not_none / total_number < 0.7,
                None,
                total_sum,
            ),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter(
        debug=False
    )  # install black and set to True to see the generated ad-hoc code
)
result = converter(input_data)
```

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate it